# HTML/JS Served by Google Apps Script

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I recently started a project using google apps script and I'm brand new to this language. This is a slightly stupid question, but one that I can't find the answer to.  In the tool, I'm serving up an HTML form that I later plan on using to create a separate spreadsheet.

```
function doGet(){
var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('form');
}
```

form.html

```
<head>
<script></script>
</head>
<body>
   ...content...
</body>
```

I had a question about the language used here. When I try and write stuff in the script tags, am I writing it in Javascript or am I writing it in Google Apps Script? More specifically, do I have access to the SpreadsheetApp class like I do in Google Apps Script?

Answer (score 0):

Client side scripts are plain JavaScripts. You don't get access to Google  libraries like `SpreadsheetApp`. You do get access to [`google.script.*`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/run) methods , but nothing else.

Answer (score 0):

## Whe using Apps Script scriptlets in your Apps Script Webapp, you can use Apps Script methods and syntax

You can use calls to Apps Script services like SpreadsheetApp in the same  manner like within your Code.gs file

Sample:

```
<head>
<script></script>
</head>
<body>
The value from cell A1 in sheet "Sheet 1" is:  <?= SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet 1").getRange("A1").getValue() ?>.
  </body>
```

More information about Apps Script WebApps and scriptlets [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/templates#index.html) and [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web).

**Note:**

To use scriptlets you need to create a `template` and `evaluate` it also you need to `return` the html output if you want to visualize it clientside.

Sample for the `doGet()` function:

```js
function doGet(){
  var html = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('form').evaluate();
  return html;
}
```

Also:

Make sure that your script has the necessary [scopes](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/concepts/scopes) to perform the request you implement in the html file, e.g. "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets.readonly".